# Just Cause 3 - How can I find the captain?

Tags: just-cause-3

In Just Cause 3, in order to liberate the town, there are a few things you have to do. One of them is to kill the Captain.

How do I find him? There is no marker in the map or screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He will randomly appear as you complete the other objects in the town. In military bases you get a commlink announcement saying "he is coming to deal with you directly", and he may come in a tank or helicopter

Comment: Yep, I saw that after a few towns.
But I had a town that I cleaned the entire town objectives and the captain was not showing.
The solution was to keep "spiderman"ing around town waiting the captain to show up.

Comment: @vianna77 you should make this an official answer because I had this issue even though I know how the killing the leader game mechanic works.

Comment: @intcreator I already checked it as the official solution 3 years ago :D Sorry if I didn't understand your comment... but the answer is already checked. There is no way to change it.

Comment: @vianna77 what I mean is you can make your comment an answer and mark that as correct.  This answer is useful information, but your comment added extra information which solved my issue.  It merits an answer by itself.

Comment: Oh, then I understand you correctly on the first time. So, once you check with the green checkmark one answer, you cannot change that answer by another. A marked answer is forever marked. Unless stackexchange changed that, but I don't think changing the marked answer is possible.